# UILocalNotification not work in iOS11

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app that works fine before iOS11 and published at AppStore. If the user use my app before iOS11, and upgrade to iOS11, my app stills work fine. However, if they are originally on iOS11, and then newly install my App, the UILocalNotifiation does not work. The daily alarm not trigger. I used UILocalNotification in my implementation, which I know already deprecated in iOS10. I checked the Notification Center, I cannot see my App in the preference pane. Any clues to solve this problem or I need to rewrite all my related codes using other framework?

```
-(void)scheduleNotification {
  LOGDEBUG(NSLog(@"schedule notification"));
  if (alertDate==nil) {
    alertDate=self.as.alertTime;
    LOGDEBUG(NSLog(@"alert Date insider notification: %@", alertDate));
  }

  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.fireDate = alertDate;
  notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  notification.alertBody = "AlertBody here...";
  notification.alertAction = "AlertAction...";
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
  notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
  notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

  LOGDEBUG(NSLog(@"To be alert at: %@", alertDate));

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


}
```

I also have these code in my AppDelegate:

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  LOGDEBUG(NSLog(@"%@", notification));
  if (notification) {
    UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:notification.alertAction otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [view show];
  }
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

And also already implemented the methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification), the `UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10. You might want to use the `UserNotications.framework` with `import UserNotifications`.

Comment: Even it is deprecated, isn't that old device should be supported for backward compatibility?

Comment: I personally don't think so, but that could be my opinion. A developer is responsible for updating the app in time, before breaking changes and so forth.